# What is the probability that a certain number of events occur?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I believe I have to use inclusion-exclusion principle, and have fiddled with it a little. I tried $$P((AB \cap C^c ) \cup (AC \cap B^c) \cup (BC \cap A^c))  $$ and used the inclusion exclusion principle treating each expression in () as an event,
but I don't think this is the right approach. Does anyone have any advice. Here is the question:

1. Events A, B, and C are defined in an outcome space S. Find expressions for the following probabilities in terms of P(A), P(B), P(C), P(AB), P(AC), P(BC), P(ABC):

(a) The probability that exactly 2  of events A, B and C occur,

(b) The probability that exactly one of these events occur,

(c) The probability that none of these events occur.

Comment: Have you drawn a triple Venn diagram?

Comment: I did, which is where I got the equation I posted. I don't see how that equation doesn't equate to part a of the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the following expression of the probability of exactly $2$ events occurring out of the $3$ events $A, B, C$ is correct:

$$P((AB \cap C^c ) \cup (AC \cap B^c) \cup (BC \cap A^c))  $$

That is:

- Let event $E_1$ denote the event $(AB \cap C^c).$
- Let event $E_2$ denote the event $(AC \cap B^c).$
- Let event $E_3$ denote the event $(BC \cap A^c).$

Then, you want to compute

$p(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3)$.

As you indicated, normally, [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) is required to compute the probability of

$$p(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3).$$

However, there is an exception:  The formula used in (1) below is perfectly fine, **if** the events $E_1, E_2$ and $E_3$ are **disjoint** events, which they are in this case.

$$p(E_1) + p(E_2) + p(E_3).\tag1 $$

It does not matter that the events $A,B,$ and $C$ are (presumably) not disjoint.  What counts is that the events $E_1, E_2$ and $E_3$ are disjoint.

If you examine the corresponding Wikipedia article that I linked to, from a backdrop of $3$ disjoint (i.e. non-intersecting) events, like $E_1, E_2$ and $E_3$, then you will see that the formula in (1) above is okay.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been trying different things for hours now because I wasn't sure if it was right or not. But do you know why I got a downvote on my post? I wasn't sure if I posted it incorrectly or something so wanted to be sure. Again thanks a lot you have saved me so much time, and I appreciate you taking time out of your day to answer.

Comment: @Orangutan On the one hand, there is no quality control, at mathSE, on downvotes.  Actually, in this instance, while I would not have downvoted your question, the downvote is not that unreasonable.  Consider the following article on the protocol for questions at MathSe : [Article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  You didn't really show any work and you are (*generally*) only supposed to ask one question per posting.  ...see next comment

Comment: @Orangutan Plus, this seems clearly to be a homework problem, where it *might seem* as if you have made no effort.  However, it seemed to me that you had researched Inclusion-Exclusion and that you were confused by the whole topic.  For example, I imagined that you were confused by the distinction (in my answer) of the events $E_1, E_2$ and $E_3$ being disjoint and the events $A, B,$ and $C$ not being disjoint.  In my judgement you had made an effort, which led to your confusion.  You simply did not **show** the effort in the question.  I read between the lines.

Comment: I checked out the article and will remember it for next time. Looking back I can see how those things might've looked. And yes exactly, I was confused by the E1 E2 and E3 being disjoint but A, B, and C not, that's why when I following through with the inclusion-exclusion principle, a lot of the values ended up being zero, which made me think I did something wrong.  Thank you for your help this far, and I hope you have a good day.

Comment: There's one extra step the OP needs to do. He or she is asked to express the probabilities in terms of $\ P(A),P(B),P(C),$$P(AB),$$P(AC),$$P(BC),\ $ and $\ P(ABC)\ $.  To do this, you need to write
$\ P(E_1)=$$P(AB)-P(ABC)\ $ etc., resulting in
$$
P(E_1)+P(E_2)+P(E_3)=P(AB)+P(AC)+P(BC)-3P(ABC)\ .
$$

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Very nice comment.

Comment: @Orangutan see the comment of lonza leggiera above.